# How can I replace link children to create a podcast-friendly feed?

Tags: php, xml, xslt, rss

I have an RSS source:

```
http://feedity.com/rss.aspx/mr1-kossuth-hu/VVdXUlY
```

```
<item>
      <title>2008. november 23.</title>
      <link>http://www.mr1-kossuth.hu/m3u/0039c36f_3003051.m3u</link>
      <description>........</description>
      <pubDate>Wed, 26 Nov 2008 00:00:00 GMT</pubDate>
    </item>
```

From this, I want to create a podcast-friendly feed. I want to replace the LINK children to:

```
http://stream001.radio.hu:8000/content/*.mp3
```

Example:

```
<item>
      <title>2008. november 23.</title>
      <link>http://stream001.radio.hu:8000/content/0039c36f_3003051.mp3</link>
      <description>........</description>
      <pubDate>Wed, 26 Nov 2008 00:00:00 GMT</pubDate>
    </item>
```

How I can do that in PHP?

Answer (score 3):

**This is a simple and pure XSLT 1.0 solution**, consisting of just 47 lines, half of which are closing tags. **The following transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

 <xsl:param name="pNewLink"
 select="'http://stream001.radio.hu:8000/content/'"/>

 <xsl:param name="pNewExt" select="'.mp3'"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="link">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>

         <xsl:variable name="vFName">
           <xsl:call-template name="GetFileName">
             <xsl:with-param name="pFPath" select="."/>
           </xsl:call-template>
         </xsl:variable>

         <xsl:value-of select="concat($pNewLink,$vFName,$pNewExt)"/>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="GetFileName">
      <xsl:param name="pFPath"/>

      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="not(contains($pFPath, '/'))">
          <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($pFPath, '.')"/>
        </xsl:when>

        <xsl:otherwise>
          <xsl:call-template name="GetFileName">
            <xsl:with-param name="pFPath"
             select="substring-after($pFPath, '/')"/>
          </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided source XML document**:

```
<item>
    <title>2008. november 23.</title>
    <link>http://www.mr1-kossuth.hu/m3u/0039c36f_3003051.m3u</link>
    <description>........</description>
    <pubDate>Wed, 26 Nov 2008 00:00:00 GMT</pubDate>
</item>
```

**produces the wanted result**:

```
<item>
    <title>2008. november 23.</title>
    <link>http://stream001.radio.hu:8000/content/0039c36f_3003051.mp3</link>
    <description>........</description>
    <pubDate>Wed, 26 Nov 2008 00:00:00 GMT</pubDate>
</item>
```

**Do note the following** specific features of this solution:

1. We use the XSLT design pattern of using and overriding the [**identity transformation**](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#copying).
2. **The template named "GetFileName**" extracts from the complete URL (passed as parameter), just the filename with the file extension stripped off. This **is a good example of a named template that calls itself recursively**.
3. The constituents of the desired new URLs are specified as global `<xsl:param>`s

Answer (score 1):

That's the sort of thing that's best done with an [XSLT](http://us.php.net/xslt).  You could write a simple XSL transform to do it, or you could do the hacky way and use the preg_match, preg_replace, and friends.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is a simple string replace:

```
$str = file_get_contents('http://feedity.com/rss.aspx/mr1-kossuth-hu/VVdXUlY');
$str = str_replace('<link>http://www.mr1-kossuth.hu/m3u/', '<link>http://stream001.radio.hu:8000/content/', $str);
$str = str_replace('m3u</link>', 'mp3</link>', $str);
```

Done!

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
 $str = file_get_contents('http://feedity.com/rss.aspx/mr1-kossuth-hu/VVdXUlY');
 $xml = simplexml_load_string($str);
if ($xml) {

$intro = str_replace('<link>http://www.mr1-kossuth.hu/m3u/', '<enclosure url="http://stream001.radio.hu:8000/content/', $xml->asXML());
$intro = str_replace('m3u</link>', 'mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />', $intro);
echo $intro;    
} else {
    $error = "Could not load intro XML file.";
}

?>
```